# Share files (eg. swf) across multiple sites using web.config

Tags: apache-flex, iis-7, coldfusion, web-config, flash

I'm managing a flash/flex system which is shared across multiple sites on the same server.

Rather than having to store the duplicates of the same swf files on each site I would like to setup a folder on the server (windows 2008 iis7) containing these swfs and allow each site to use the same swf files.  I would like to include these files somehow so the user thinks the swf files are coming from the source domain not the a shared domain.

I'm used to using coldfusion mapping to share files but this isn't available for non-coldfusion files i.e. swf

I wondered would it be possible to rewrite urls in my web.config file to these swf files?

Please could someone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks
David

Comment: Is it your server or are you using a hosting site?

Comment: thanks for the reply - we have a dedicated web server which hosts multiple websites

Comment: We use ColdFusion mapping to a directory that has subdirectories where we store images and javascript files.  These are not coldfusion files.  We don't do much with swf's but if we set up a suitable subdirectory for them, they would be available to all our sites just as the image and js files are now.

Answer (score 5):

Can you do a "virtual directory" in your web server?

IIS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

Apache: http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-virtual-directory-apache

It's much like a CF mapping does for CF, but this on the web server level, making the mapped resources accessible via URL.

Comment: It's not 'exactly like' a CF mapping as CF mappings are not web accessible but this is the right solution.

Comment: Sorry, poor wording on my part, I just wanted to point out the similarity, especially if cf mapping are already understood. I'll revise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about setting up your own CDN (content delivery network), then just setup another website simply to serve up all your graphics, scripts, CSS, swfs etc.

Comment: but I don't want to have www.SiteA.com getting the swf from www.sharedsite.com/myfile.swf it should be included or mapped on the server

Comment: I have no doubt this would work, but it sounds like overkill to me.  With Flash, it could also present cross-domain issues if the SWF is trying to make remote to a domain other than the "CDN" domain.  The other answer--to create a virtual directory--is simple to set up would be my recommendation.